# I am using WSO2 ESB 5.0.0 with JDK 1.8.0_91 in windows 7 64-bit. I want to resolve the errors in the following situations

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I am beginner to WSO2 ESB. Previously, I was running ESB server in command prompt using command:

> **C:/Program Files/wso2-5.0/bin> wso2server.bat --run**

It responded successfully and server was running fine.

I stopped the server in command prompt and deployed the "WSO2QuickStartGuideCapp_1.0.0.CAR" file as per example [sending a simple message using WSO2-ESB](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Sending+a+Simple+Message) using Eclipse **wso2esb-tooling-eclipse-jee-mars-win64-x86_64-5-1.0.0**.

However, I am able to get the requests and response.

But, the Server thrown the following errors (Please Scroll Down for the errors) on the eclipse console:

```
[2016-10-25 10:59:50,591]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: org.wso2.carbon.sts-5.1.1 - 
[2016-10-25 10:59:50,701]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: org.wso2.carbon.tryit-4.5.4 - 
[2016-10-25 10:59:50,919]  INFO - CarbonServerManager Repository       : C:/Program Files/wso2esb-5.0.0/repository/deployment/server/
[2016-10-25 10:59:50,997]  INFO - TenantLoadingConfig Using tenant lazy loading policy...
[2016-10-25 10:59:51,029]  INFO - PermissionUpdater Permission cache updated for tenant -1234
[2016-10-25 10:59:51,091]  INFO - RuleEngineConfigDS Successfully registered the Rule Config service
[2016-10-25 10:59:51,216]  INFO - ServiceBusInitializer Starting ESB...
[2016-10-25 10:59:51,231]  INFO - ServiceBusInitializer Initializing Apache Synapse...
[2016-10-25 10:59:51,247]  INFO - SynapseControllerFactory Using Synapse home : C:\Program Files\wso2esb-5.0.0\.
[2016-10-25 10:59:51,247]  INFO - SynapseControllerFactory Using synapse.xml location : C:\Program Files\wso2esb-5.0.0\.\.\repository\deployment\server\synapse-configs\default
[2016-10-25 10:59:51,247]  INFO - SynapseControllerFactory Using server name : localhost
[2016-10-25 10:59:51,247]  INFO - SynapseControllerFactory The timeout handler will run every : 15s
[2016-10-25 10:59:51,263]  INFO - Axis2SynapseController Initializing Synapse at : Tue Oct 25 10:59:51 IST 2016
[2016-10-25 10:59:51,278]  INFO - RuntimeStatisticCollector Statistics Entry Expiration time set to 136000 milliseconds
[2016-10-25 10:59:51,278]  INFO - CarbonSynapseController Loading the mediation configuration from the file system
[2016-10-25 10:59:51,278]  INFO - MultiXMLConfigurationBuilder Building synapse configuration from the synapse artifact repository at : .\.\repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs\default
[2016-10-25 10:59:51,372]  INFO - XMLConfigurationBuilder Generating the Synapse configuration model by parsing the XML configuration
[2016-10-25 10:59:51,465]  INFO - DependencyTracker Sequence : fault was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2016-10-25 10:59:51,481]  INFO - DependencyTracker Sequence : main was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2016-10-25 10:59:51,481]  INFO - SynapseConfigurationBuilder Loaded Synapse configuration from the artifact repository at : .\.\repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs\default
[2016-10-25 10:59:51,481]  INFO - DependencyTracker Local entry : SERVER_HOST was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2016-10-25 10:59:51,481]  INFO - DependencyTracker Local entry : SERVER_IP was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2016-10-25 10:59:51,481]  INFO - Axis2SynapseController Loading mediator extensions...
[2016-10-25 10:59:51,512]  INFO - DeploymentInterceptor Deploying Axis2 service: echo {super-tenant}
[2016-10-25 10:59:51,512]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: Echo.aar - file:/C:/Program Files/wso2esb-5.0.0/repository/deployment/server/axis2services/Echo.aar
[2016-10-25 10:59:51,543]  INFO - DeploymentInterceptor Deploying Axis2 service: Version {super-tenant}
[2016-10-25 10:59:51,543]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: Version.aar - file:/C:/Program Files/wso2esb-5.0.0/repository/deployment/server/axis2services/Version.aar
[2016-10-25 10:59:51,575]  INFO - EventPublisherDeployer Event Publisher deployment held back and in inactive state :MessageFlowConfigurationPublisher.xml, Stream validation exception : Stream org.wso2.esb.analytics.stream.ConfigEntry:1.0.0 does not exist
[2016-10-25 10:59:51,575]  INFO - EventPublisherDeployer Event Publisher deployment held back and in inactive state :MessageFlowStatisticsPublisher.xml, Stream validation exception : Stream org.wso2.esb.analytics.stream.FlowEntry:1.0.0 does not exist
[2016-10-25 10:59:51,637]  INFO - EventPublisherDeployer Event Publisher undeployed successfully : MessageFlowConfigurationPublisher.xml
[2016-10-25 10:59:52,137]  INFO - EventJunction WSO2EventConsumer added to the junction. Stream:org.wso2.esb.analytics.stream.ConfigEntry:1.0.0
[2016-10-25 10:59:52,153]  INFO - EventPublisherDeployer Event Publisher configuration successfully deployed and in active state : MessageFlowConfigurationPublisher
[2016-10-25 10:59:52,153]  INFO - EventStreamDeployer Stream definition is deployed successfully  : org.wso2.esb.analytics.stream.ConfigEntry:1.0.0
[2016-10-25 10:59:52,153]  INFO - EventPublisherDeployer Event Publisher undeployed successfully : MessageFlowStatisticsPublisher.xml
[2016-10-25 10:59:52,168]  INFO - EventJunction WSO2EventConsumer added to the junction. Stream:org.wso2.esb.analytics.stream.FlowEntry:1.0.0
[2016-10-25 10:59:52,168]  INFO - EventPublisherDeployer Event Publisher configuration successfully deployed and in active state : MessageFlowStatisticsPublisher
[2016-10-25 10:59:52,168]  INFO - EventStreamDeployer Stream definition is deployed successfully  : org.wso2.esb.analytics.stream.FlowEntry:1.0.0
[2016-10-25 10:59:52,168]  INFO - Axis2SynapseController Deploying the Synapse service...
[2016-10-25 10:59:52,168]  INFO - Axis2SynapseController Deploying Proxy services...
[2016-10-25 10:59:52,168]  INFO - Axis2SynapseController Deploying EventSources...
[2016-10-25 10:59:52,200]  INFO - ServerManager Server ready for processing...
[2016-10-25 10:59:52,278]  INFO - MediationStatisticsComponent JMX mediation statistic publishing enabled for tenant: -1234
[2016-10-25 10:59:52,278]  INFO - MediationStatisticsComponent DAS mediation statistic publishing enabled for tenant: -1234
[2016-10-25 10:59:53,307]  INFO - PassThroughHttpListener Starting Pass-through HTTP Listener...
[2016-10-25 10:59:53,307]  INFO - PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager Pass-through HTTP Listener started on 0.0.0.0:8280
[2016-10-25 10:59:53,307]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLListener Starting Pass-through HTTPS Listener...
[2016-10-25 10:59:53,307]  INFO - PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager Pass-through HTTPS Listener started on 0.0.0.0:8243
[2016-10-25 10:59:53,323]  INFO - ApplicationManager Deploying Carbon Application : SampleServicesCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car...
[2016-10-25 10:59:53,822] ERROR - DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while trying to connect to ssl://localhost:7712
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointSecurityException: Error while trying to connect to ssl://localhost:7712
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:61)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.client.AbstractClientPoolFactory.makeObject(AbstractClientPoolFactory.java:39)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:91)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not connect to localhost on port 7712
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:237)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.getClientSocket(TSSLTransportFactory.java:169)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:56)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:233)
    ... 11 more
[2016-10-25 10:59:53,826] ERROR - DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointSecurityException: Error while trying to connect to ssl://localhost:7712
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:61)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.client.AbstractClientPoolFactory.makeObject(AbstractClientPoolFactory.java:39)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:91)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not connect to localhost on port 7712
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:237)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.getClientSocket(TSSLTransportFactory.java:169)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:56)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:233)
    ... 11 more
[2016-10-25 10:59:54,949]  INFO - API Initializing API: HealthcareAPI
[2016-10-25 10:59:54,952]  INFO - DependencyTracker API : HealthcareAPI was added to the Synapse configuration successfully - [ Deployed From Artifact Container: SampleServicesCompositeApplication ] 
[2016-10-25 10:59:54,953]  INFO - APIDeployer API named 'HealthcareAPI' has been deployed from file : C:\Program Files\wso2esb-5.0.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1477373393323SampleServicesCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car\HealthcareAPI_1.0.0\HealthcareAPI-1.0.0.xml
[2016-10-25 10:59:54,964]  INFO - DependencyTracker Endpoint : QueryDoctorEP was added to the Synapse configuration successfully - [ Deployed From Artifact Container: SampleServicesCompositeApplication ] 
[2016-10-25 10:59:54,965]  INFO - EndpointDeployer Endpoint named 'QueryDoctorEP' has been deployed from file : C:\Program Files\wso2esb-5.0.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1477373393323SampleServicesCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car\QueryDoctorEP_1.0.0\QueryDoctorEP-1.0.0.xml
[2016-10-25 10:59:54,965]  INFO - ApplicationManager Successfully Deployed Carbon Application : SampleServicesCompositeApplication_1.0.0 {super-tenant}
[2016-10-25 10:59:54,966]  INFO - ApplicationManager Deploying Carbon Application : WSO2QuickStartGuideCapp_1.0.0.car...
[2016-10-25 10:59:55,081]  INFO - API Initializing API: HospitalServiceApi
[2016-10-25 10:59:55,081]  INFO - DependencyTracker API : HospitalServiceApi was added to the Synapse configuration successfully - [ Deployed From Artifact Container: WSO2QuickStartGuideCapp ] 
[2016-10-25 10:59:55,081]  INFO - APIDeployer API named 'HospitalServiceApi' has been deployed from file : C:\Program Files\wso2esb-5.0.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1477373394966WSO2QuickStartGuideCapp_1.0.0.car\HospitalServiceApi_1.0.0\HospitalServiceApi-1.0.0.xml
[2016-10-25 10:59:55,083]  INFO - DependencyTracker Endpoint : discountEligibility was added to the Synapse configuration successfully - [ Deployed From Artifact Container: WSO2QuickStartGuideCapp ] 
[2016-10-25 10:59:55,083]  INFO - EndpointDeployer Endpoint named 'discountEligibility' has been deployed from file : C:\Program Files\wso2esb-5.0.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1477373394966WSO2QuickStartGuideCapp_1.0.0.car\discountEligibility_1.0.0\discountEligibility-1.0.0.xml
[2016-10-25 10:59:55,084]  INFO - DependencyTracker Endpoint : getPaymentDetails was added to the Synapse configuration successfully - [ Deployed From Artifact Container: WSO2QuickStartGuideCapp ] 
[2016-10-25 10:59:55,085]  INFO - EndpointDeployer Endpoint named 'getPaymentDetails' has been deployed from file : C:\Program Files\wso2esb-5.0.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1477373394966WSO2QuickStartGuideCapp_1.0.0.car\getPaymentDetails_1.0.0\getPaymentDetails-1.0.0.xml
[2016-10-25 10:59:55,087]  INFO - DependencyTracker Endpoint : channellingFee was added to the Synapse configuration successfully - [ Deployed From Artifact Container: WSO2QuickStartGuideCapp ] 
[2016-10-25 10:59:55,087]  INFO - EndpointDeployer Endpoint named 'channellingFee' has been deployed from file : C:\Program Files\wso2esb-5.0.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1477373394966WSO2QuickStartGuideCapp_1.0.0.car\channellingFee_1.0.0\channellingFee-1.0.0.xml
[2016-10-25 10:59:55,372]  INFO - DependencyTracker Sequence : APIInSequence was added to the Synapse configuration successfully - [ Deployed From Artifact Container: WSO2QuickStartGuideCapp ] 
[2016-10-25 10:59:55,373]  INFO - SequenceDeployer Sequence named 'APIInSequence' has been deployed from file : C:\Program Files\wso2esb-5.0.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1477373394966WSO2QuickStartGuideCapp_1.0.0.car\APIInSequence_1.0.0\APIInSequence-1.0.0.xml
[2016-10-25 10:59:55,378]  INFO - DependencyTracker Sequence : faultSequence was added to the Synapse configuration successfully - [ Deployed From Artifact Container: WSO2QuickStartGuideCapp ] 
[2016-10-25 10:59:55,378]  INFO - SequenceDeployer Sequence named 'faultSequence' has been deployed from file : C:\Program Files\wso2esb-5.0.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1477373394966WSO2QuickStartGuideCapp_1.0.0.car\faultSequence_1.0.0\faultSequence-1.0.0.xml
[2016-10-25 10:59:55,378]  INFO - DependencyTracker Endpoint : reserveAppointmentEp was added to the Synapse configuration successfully - [ Deployed From Artifact Container: WSO2QuickStartGuideCapp ] 
[2016-10-25 10:59:55,378]  INFO - EndpointDeployer Endpoint named 'reserveAppointmentEp' has been deployed from file : C:\Program Files\wso2esb-5.0.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1477373394966WSO2QuickStartGuideCapp_1.0.0.car\reserveAppointmentEp_1.0.0\reserveAppointmentEp-1.0.0.xml
[2016-10-25 10:59:55,378]  INFO - DependencyTracker Endpoint : settlePayment was added to the Synapse configuration successfully - [ Deployed From Artifact Container: WSO2QuickStartGuideCapp ] 
[2016-10-25 10:59:55,378]  INFO - EndpointDeployer Endpoint named 'settlePayment' has been deployed from file : C:\Program Files\wso2esb-5.0.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1477373394966WSO2QuickStartGuideCapp_1.0.0.car\settlePayment_1.0.0\settlePayment-1.0.0.xml
[2016-10-25 10:59:55,378]  INFO - ApplicationManager Successfully Deployed Carbon Application : WSO2QuickStartGuideCapp_1.0.0 {super-tenant}
[2016-10-25 10:59:55,378]  INFO - NioSelectorPool Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
[2016-10-25 10:59:55,448]  INFO - NioSelectorPool Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
[2016-10-25 10:59:55,561]  INFO - TaskServiceImpl Task service starting in STANDALONE mode...
[2016-10-25 10:59:55,590]  INFO - NTaskTaskManager Initialized task manager. Tenant [-1234]
[2016-10-25 10:59:55,665]  INFO - JMXServerManager JMX Service URL  : service:jmx:rmi://localhost:11111/jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/jmxrmi
[2016-10-25 10:59:55,665]  INFO - StartupFinalizerServiceComponent Server           :  WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus-5.0.0
[2016-10-25 10:59:55,665]  INFO - StartupFinalizerServiceComponent WSO2 Carbon started in 53 sec
[2016-10-25 10:59:55,995]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent Mgt Console URL  : https://192.168.100.196:9443/carbon/
[2016-10-25 11:00:22,726]  WARN - DataEndpointGroup No receiver is reachable at reconnection, will try to reconnect every 30 sec
[2016-10-25 11:00:23,728] ERROR - DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while trying to connect to ssl://localhost:7712
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointSecurityException: Error while trying to connect to ssl://localhost:7712
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:61)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.client.AbstractClientPoolFactory.makeObject(AbstractClientPoolFactory.java:39)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:91)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not connect to localhost on port 7712
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:237)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.getClientSocket(TSSLTransportFactory.java:169)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:56)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:233)
    ... 11 more
[2016-10-25 11:00:23,732] ERROR - DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointSecurityException: Error while trying to connect to ssl://localhost:7712
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:61)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.client.AbstractClientPoolFactory.makeObject(AbstractClientPoolFactory.java:39)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:91)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not connect to localhost on port 7712
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:237)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.getClientSocket(TSSLTransportFactory.java:169)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:56)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:233)
    ... 11 more
```

And, Now while re-running the server on the command prompt also throws the same errors as above. But, yet I am able to login in the carbon management console using:

Username : admin

Password : admin

Please help me resolving the errors specified.

```
[2016-10-25 10:59:53,822] ERROR - DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while trying to connect to ssl://localhost:7712
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointSecurityException: Error while trying to connect to ssl://localhost:7712
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:61)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.client.AbstractClientPoolFactory.makeObject(AbstractClientPoolFactory.java:39)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:91)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not connect to localhost on port 7712
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:237)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.getClientSocket(TSSLTransportFactory.java:169)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:56)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:233)
    ... 11 more
[2016-10-25 10:59:53,826] ERROR - DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointSecurityException: Error while trying to connect to ssl://localhost:7712
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:61)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.client.AbstractClientPoolFactory.makeObject(AbstractClientPoolFactory.java:39)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:91)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not connect to localhost on port 7712
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:237)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.getClientSocket(TSSLTransportFactory.java:169)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:56)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:233)
    ... 11 more
```

**Thanks in Advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same error, and after some investigation I found out that ESB carbon was trying to connect to ssl port 7712 based on default Thrift receiverURL, but it would crash because I had no Thrift server started.

I found that out when I lauched esb analytics to investigate the crash, and it started the Thrift server,which would listen to the same port.
After that, the crash was gone.